# IFCSpaces not visible in ACC Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

We have some IFC files in the ACC that contain `IFCSpace`'s. However, the problem is that the viewer from ACC is not able to display these `IFCSpace`'s visually, even though the model browser tells us that they are present.

Now we have a small internal application that also uses the Autodesk viewer. It shows the bounding boxes of the `IFCSpace`'s in the same IFC. If you press "ESC" the `IFCSpaces` are even colored transparent.

Why does the ACC Viewer not show the `IFCSpace`'s? I have already tried to play around with the NOP_VIEWER variable (showAll() etc.) but have not been able to find a solution.

Version number of the viewers:

- ACC: v1.52.0_7.94.4_2.0.816
- Autodesk API Viewer: v7.94.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the viewer in Autodesk Docs, well-known as ACC Docs, doesn't load hidden geometries (e.g., Rooms, Spaces) by default, which is our ACC product team's decision, as far as I know.

In APS Viewer (formerly Forge Viewer), we can see the hidden geometries by passing `skipHiddenFragments: false` when loading the same model hosted on ACC/BIM360, which is the default in APS Viewer.

```js
// in APS viewer
viewer.loadDocumentNode(
    doc,
    bubble,
    {
        skipHiddenFragments: false
    }
);
```

However, this option in the viewer of ACC & BIM360 is `skipHiddenFragments: true` by default. So, this is why we cannot see Rooms on the viewer of ACC/BIM360.

If you want to change this default behavior on ACC/BIM360, I would advise you to raise your voice via our product support: https://www.autodesk.com/support/contact-support

Our apologize for the inconvenience!

Comment: Hi Eason! Thanks for your quick reply. Is it somehow possible to trigger a reload via the NOP_VIEWER (ACC Docs) and set `skipHiddenFragments: false`?

Comment: It's not recommended to use NOP_VIEWER, which is for debugging only. Please don't use it in production.